# Using ssh fails on home network

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have two pcs on a network, one have address 192.168.1.4 with username bakerally,

however when I'm trying `ssh bakerally@192.168.1.4`
, it says

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.4 port 22: No route to host
```

even though I tried to disable firewall using this command

```
sudo ufw disable
```

Comment: did you install openssh_server `apt-get install openssh_server` on the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a networking issue. Can you ping 192.168.1.4? If your host IP is in the 192.168.1.X range, look at the subnet masks. If it is in a different network, you probably have a gateway/routing issue.

Comment: no, its on the same network because i can ping from both PCs

Comment: @Noor: "No route to host" means you have a networking issue or mistyped the address.